# why calculate result is -3.0531133177192E-16

Tags: php

Why the code's result is that? -3.0531133177192E-16

I think the result should be zero.

```
        $a = floatval('-0.92');
        $b = floatval('-0.55');
        $c = floatval('1.38');
        $d = floatval('0');
        $e = floatval('0.09');
        $temp=$a+$b+$c+$d+$e;
        var_dump($temp);
        die();
```

I'm a php fresher, I'm really confused by this result, So any answer will be appreciated.

Comment: This question is really language agnostic and the behavior is typical of floating point arithmetic. A quick google will reveal plenty of articles on both SO and other sites that cover how this happens.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Float_(computing)#Accuracy_problems

Comment: You can do.  Some languages have exact-precision types, but PHP, unfortunately, does not have.

for more info  http://in3.php.net/manual/en/function.bcadd.php

    $temp= bcadd(bcadd(bcadd(bcadd($a, $b, 2),$c,2),$d,2),$e,2);
            
    echo $temp;

output: 0.00